# Gatsby build doesn't take react bootstrap size prefix after page reload

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, gatsby, react-bootstrap

I am having an issue with Gatsby `bootstrap` or `react-bootstrap` (not sure yet, most likely it is bootstrap). Everything looks great when I build and serve gatsby website, it has all bootstrap classes and nice grid ( 2 columns, one is `md="8"` another is `md="4"`). But once I reload the page and when I inspect the code in the Chrome browser, bootstrap classes disappear.

Code in Gatsby page (added className just to make sure that it is not coming after reaload):

```
{window.innerWidth > 992 ? (
  <Col md="8">
    <NameAndHealine />
    <ListingText />
  </Col>
  <Col md="4">
    <PricingSidebBar />
  </Col>
) : (
  <Col xs="12">
     <NameAndHealine />
  </Col>
  <Col xs="12">
     <PricingSidebBar />
  </Col>
  <Col xs="12" className="mt-5">
     <ListingText />
  </Col>
)
```

Code example before page reload:

```
<div class="col-md-8">...</div>
<div class="col-md-4">...</div>
```

Code example after page reload:

```
<div class="col-12">...</div>
<div class="col-12">...</div>
```

Steps what I tried to solve the problem:

1. Import `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js` inside `gatsby-browser.js`
2. Add extra className with bootstrap classes to make sure it is not coming after page reload.

**EDIT:**

I found the issue, it is with `window.innerWidth` as I was ordering components depending on it. I changed it to multiple rows and set display classes for different screens. After page reload Gatsby doesn't take classes when it is inside `if (window.innerWidth > 992)` (why?). If someone knows the answer please let me know, thanks.

**EDIT 2**

Added extra code above

Comment: It looks like something is overwriting the div classes on runtime. Please provide more code so we can be more specific

Comment: Hello @Kingalione, please see the updated code above. Thanks